# How to remove spaces inbetween words before indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I remove spaces between words before indexing?

For example: 
I want to be able to search for 0123 7784 9809 7893
when I query "0123 7784 9809 7893", "0123778498097893", or "0123-7784-9809-7893"

My idea is to remove all spaces and dashes and combine the partial into a whole string (0123 7784 9809 7893 to 0123778498097893) before indexing, and also adding an analyzer in the query part so as to find my desired result.

I have tried

```
"char_filter" : {
            "neglect_dash_and_space_filter" : {
              "type" : "mapping",
              "mappings" : [
                "- => ",
                "' ' => "
              ]
            }
```

It seems that only dash is removed but not spaces. Tested custom shingle, but still not working. Kindly advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pattern replace filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html)

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "whitespace_remove": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[^0-9]", ---> it will replace anything other than digits
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "whitespace_remove"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use \uXXXX notation for spaces:
EDIT1:

```
PUT index41
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "\\u0020 => ",
            "- => "
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any ways to use char_filter to achieve it?

Comment: Hi  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.